# display: flex & justify-content: space-evenly

Tags: javascript, html, css, display

guys.

Just a question about CSS and javascript.

I have this code but I need to make the input areas centered.

For some reason they are not aligned even with the same length.

I know that the text size effects the position of the flex, but I didn't understand how.

Sorry for the silly question, I'm just starting to learn it.

```
<div class="playersDiv">
            <div class="players player1">
                <h2>Player Name</h2>
                <div class="showInput">
                    <input type="playerInput1" name="playerInput1" id="playerInput1">
                    <button class="addPlayerBtn">Add Player</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="scoreDiv">
                <p>Input below the quantity of each tile in the end of the game:</p>
                <div class="scoreItem">
                    <h3>Forest</h3>
                    <input type="number" name="fnum" id="fnum">
                    <p>10</p>
                </div>
                <div class="scoreItem">
                    <h3>Town</h3>
                    <input type="number" name="fnum" id="fnum">
                    <p>10</p>
                </div>
                <div class="scoreItem">
                    <h3>Production</h3>
                    <input type="number" name="fnum" id="fnum">
                    <p>10</p>
                </div>
                <div class="scoreItem">
                    <h3>Factory</h3>
                    <input type="number" name="fnum" id="fnum">
                    <p>10</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

.scoreItem{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    margin: 0 auto 0.5rem auto;
    height: 2rem;
}
#fnum {
    margin: 0 1rem;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, the fnum id should be a unique ID for one element on the page. In this instance you should use classes instead of id:

```
<input type="number" name="fnum" class="fnum">
```

Then, in your css you should use . instead of #:

```
.fnum {
   margin: 0 1rem;
}
```

The name attribute should also be unique, as this is the way you will access the data from your backend. e.g.

```
<input type="number" name="production-fnum" class="fnum">
<input type="number" name="factory-fnum" class="fnum">
```

Presuming the CSS you have is written in a separate .css file, or in  tags.
The space-evenly attribute is affected by the width of the elements,
You can add a fixed width to the h3 and input elements with:

```css
h3 {
  width: 150px;
}
input {
  width: 150px;
}
```

or, you can give each h3 element a class and add the style to that, and style the fnum class we created earlier e.g.

```
<h3 class="label">Factory</h3>
.label{width: 150px}
.fnum{width: 150px}
```

Also, I would use a label instead of h3 (https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_label.asp)

Comment: Thanks! It worked great. It's quite anoying to adjust this width for a responsive page.

Answer (score 1):

I can offer such a solution. Set this rule in your css:

```
.scoreItem h3 {
   width: 90px;
}
```

Where width 90px is the width of the longest tag `h3` - **Production**.

```css
.scoreItem{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    margin: 0 auto 0.5rem auto;
    height: 2rem;
}

#fnum {
    margin: 0 1rem;
}

.scoreItem h3 {
  width: 90px;
}
```

```html
<div class="playersDiv">
            <div class="players player1">
                <h2>Player Name</h2>
                <div class="showInput">
                    <input type="playerInput1" name="playerInput1" id="playerInput1">
                    <button class="addPlayerBtn">Add Player</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="scoreDiv">
                <p>Input below the quantity of each tile in the end of the game:</p>
                <div class="scoreItem">
                    <h3>Forest</h3>
                    <input type="number" name="fnum" id="fnum">
                    <p>10</p>
                </div>
                <div class="scoreItem">
                    <h3>Town</h3>
                    <input type="number" name="fnum" id="fnum">
                    <p>10</p>
                </div>
                <div class="scoreItem">
                    <h3>Production</h3>
                    <input type="number" name="fnum" id="fnum">
                    <p>10</p>
                </div>
                <div class="scoreItem">
                    <h3>Factory</h3>
                    <input type="number" name="fnum" id="fnum">
                    <p>10</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```